# What is the next stage after Sanyasa?

Tags: samskara, sanyasi

In [one of my questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5291/what-is-the-purpose-of-own-antyesthi-cremation-before-taking-sanyasa) I asked about Sanyasa and its related things. In Sanyasa ashram, a sanyasi wears saffrons robs and removes or keeps panchkeshi.

I was under the impression that Sanyasa is the final state but later on from one spiritual book, I came to know that there is one more state after sanyasa. But I didn't find what is it.

- What is the next stage after Sanyasa?
- What is the purpose of having a next stage after Sanyasa?

Comment: good question sir. which book is that? it would be great if you could add a citation to that. thanks. because typically different philosophers have various interpretations. It is important to know what they mean, in addition to just the facts

Comment: The Book is not available online, the content is as follows--" as my Guru has given me next diksha/avasta (after sanyasa) that I don't need to wear any cloths but as I am leaving in this world, that's why I have chosen to wear White rob"--- As per my understanding/guess Swami savitanand ji is talking about Avdhoot diksha as particularly he mentioned about cloths. But anyways I even don't know what is avdhoot diksha and it's purpose of giving.

Answer (score 5):

There is no recognized or formal stage after sannyas. Individual maths or individual gurus may give some title or other such thing, but there is no generally accepted stage after sannyas nor is there anything in scripture.

There are different sects of sadhus and different sects will wear different colors. Most people when they think of sannyas, think of those whose lineage traces to the maths started by Sankara, and they wear saffron. But there are other sects and those sadhus do not always wear saffron.

Go to Kankhal, you see a lot of saffron - but you can also see many many different colors there!